# Error: Unable to access integer value which is size of list

Tags: java, arraylist, package

I am trying to access the ThiArrayList.getAge().size() from my class NormalizeInput.java

Here is how my package structure looks like:-Both classes ThisArrayList and Normalize Input are public classes

[image]

I am getting the error create class temp,y as  in my code ,

```
  public class NormalizeInput {

        List<Double> temp=new ArrayList<>();
        temp=ThisArrayList.getAge();
        int y=temp.size();

        for(int a;a<=y;a++) {

        }
    }
```

And here is what my getAge() Method looks like:-

```
public static List<Double> getAge() {
    return ages;
}
```

Where am I doing wrong,Why i am not able to access int value y?

Comment: Post your code rather than structure for better help

Comment: What does `getAge` returns ? What is its visibility ? You should post some code for us to be able to help you. We can't guess just by viewing a package structure

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: From where your static variable `ages` comes from in the class `ThisArrayList` ?

Comment: Here I was trying to access the value of y and increment it but I was unable to do so and my netbeans editor gives the sugeestion create class temp in normalizeneuralnetwork and create class x, I am confused why I am not able to access these values?

Comment: @neomega I have created a static list of ages in the class ThisArrayList

Comment: @rozi i don't see anything that could cause an error actually. The only problem i see in your code is instantiating an `ArrayList`and discarding it on the next line by assigning `ThisArrayList.getAge()` to `temp`. Does your code compile and runs ? I don't understand the error you are indicating neither the netbeans' suggestion here.

Comment: But if I keep it inside some method as    :-                                          public void setNormalizeInput()
    {   -----My Code--------    
      }                                                                                                     .............It works fine

Comment: @rozi I just saw, you forgot to initialize your `a` (to 0 i guess) variable in your `for` loop

Comment: Is it is some feature of java I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in your getAge() method..

**test class**

```
class test{
    public static List<Double> getAge() {
        List<Double> ages = new ArrayList<>();
        //add some value here
        return ages;
    }
}
```

**display method**

```
public static void display(){
        test t = new test();
        List<Double> temp=new ArrayList<>();
        temp=t.getAge();
        int y=temp.size();
        System.out.println(y);
        for(int a=0; a<=y; a++) {
             //Your code
        }
    }
```

**Mmin method**

```
public static void main(String arr[]){
     display();
}
```

This is working fine with me.

Comment: I was accessing it from the class other than main and when I included it inside a function    `public void setNormalizeInput()
    {       
    List<Double> temp=new ArrayList<>();
    temp=ThisArrayList.getAge();
    int y=temp.size();
    
    for(int a=0;a<=y;a++)
    {
        
    }
    }`,,,,,,,, my code is Running fine............Never worked without a main method........Is it some feature of java I am missing?

Comment: so do you want call a method without main method?